# Kendo UI Calendar

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I've been working with Kendo UI Web, and when I looked at the Calendar widget and there is a syntax like this `${ data.value }` I'm sure that that syntax echos a value. And that syntax was new to me and I can't seem to find a documentation about it when I googled. Can someone point me to the right direction? And can I populate the dates option of the Calendar widget like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: getHolidaysURL,
  success: function(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    var holidayDates = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var dateSplit = json[i].date;

      holidayDates.push(new Date(dateSplit[0], dateSplit[1], dateSplit[2]));
    }

    $('#holiday-calendar').data('kendoCalendar').options.dates = holidayDates;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**${ }** is the same as **#: #**. [Here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) is more information about **#: #**.

Regarding the dates I am afraid that options set after initializing the widget wont be taken into account. Why don't you destroy the widget and recreate it inside of the success callback with the desired options?

Comment: Thanks Pechka. In that case I guess I won't use the dates option of the Calendar widget then, because in my scenario I'm trying to mark the dates in the Calendar with a specified date which are holidays. It will be really hard to mark the dates if there will be two arrays which are "non-working" and "working" holidays each will have a different image as a marker.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Pechka said about `${}` and instead of destroying and re-creating the `widget`, you might try:

```
var cal = $('#holiday-calendar').data('kendoCalendar');
cal.options.dates = holidayDates;
cal.navigateToPast();
cal.navigateToFuture();
```

This is not an actual **solution** but a trick for forcing the calendar to `refresh` and so far it works. What it does is move to the past and then to the future in your `calendar` forcing the `redraw` of the `calendar`.

It might actually produce some sort of flickering depending on the speed of the browser and the screen of the computer **BUT** it will be less than destroying and re-creating a widget.